# How can I get the homepage from the loop?

Tags: pages, get-posts, homepage

From the get Get_Pages documentation (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) I understand it should look more or less like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); 
?>
```

But where do I specify that it's the homepage I'd like to get?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what your trying to do.

If you want to get the page content in another template or functions file and your home page is a page that you created in the dashboard and set as the `static front page` you can use `get_page_by_path` function like this:

```
get_page_by_path('the_path_of_the_page'); // Usually will be 'home'
```

Or if you want to use `get_pages` you can do the following:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_name' => 'the_slug_of_the_page' // This also will likely be 'home' for the home page'
); 
$home = get_pages($args); 
?>
```

See [get_page_by_path](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path) in the Codex.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem the path of the homepage is "home". How can I find it?

Comment: If you have a static page, in your admin dashboard in the `pages` menu, search for a page with a `- Front Page` in the front of the name. e.g `Home - Front Page`. If you don't see any, that means that you have a static file, this cold be a file called `home.php` or `front-page.php`. Go to your theme directory and see if you find it there.

Comment: Thanks. So in the get_page_by_path, the path is actually the path of the template/php file. Right? 
As for the get_pages option, I don't understand what you mean by 'the_slug_of_the_page' when referring to the homepage. My understanding is that the slug is what appears after the base URL, which in case of the homepage is empty.

Comment: No, the path in this case is technically the slug of the page. But when using child pages e.g `mysite.com/page/child-page`, the path is `page/child-page` (this isn't relevant in your case, but is good to know). Yes the slug is what appears after the name of the page, and when you set a static page, it doesn't appear in the url, but the page still have it.